# Android : How To Sort An Arraylist of Special Characters Alphabetically?

Tags: java, android, string, sorting, special-characters

I am developing an android application where i have data in Norwegian language. Now , i have to sort a list of name alphabetically where the names contain special norwegian characters.

```
    Comparator<SetGetMethods> comperator = new Comparator<SetGetMethods>() {

        public int compare(SetGetMethods object1, SetGetMethods object2) {

                return object1.getCityname().compareToIgnoreCase(object2.getCityname());

        }

    };
    Collections.sort(temp, comperator);
```

I used the code above to sort the list alphabetically. But after sorting , the names with normal characters shown on top and names with special norwegian characters shown below them. For example , the list is shown like below ,

Arendal
Bergen
Drammen
Ålesund -> ( This should be on top , before Arendal after sorting )

So , my question is , how can i sort a list alphabetically where the list data contains special characters(Norwegian characters). I will appreciate any suggestion , idea or sample code to solve the problem. Thanks .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the example based on Norwegian in the [JavaDoc for the RuleBasedCollator class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html).

Based on that, I've created this example that puts Å before A based on a accent difference -- note the use of ';' to put \u00E5 before A. So this works for your example input, but you'll need to add other accented Norwegian characters based on your knowledge of the language to complete the `norwegian` comparison string.

```
String norwegian = "< a, \u00E5;A< b,B< c,C< d,D< e,E< f,F< g,G< h,H< i,I< j,J" +
                   "< k,K< l,L< m,M< n,N< o,O< p,P< q,Q< r,R< s,S< t,T" +
                   "< u,U< v,V< w,W< x,X< y,Y< z,Z";                      
RuleBasedCollator myNorwegian = new RuleBasedCollator(norwegian);     
List<String> words = 
  Arrays.asList("Arendal Bergen Drammen \u00E5lesund".split("\\s"));     
System.out.println(words);     
Collections.sort(words, myNorwegian);     
System.out.println(words);
```

Comment: I am getting confused as this class is totally new to me. Can you provide me some sample example to understand the concept of collator and how it is used to sort an arraylist. That will be more appreciated.

Comment: hi Andy , your example worked fine, Thanks for that again. Now, if i want to sort an array list of objects , where an object contains several information like name , address etc then how can i sort the whole array list alphabetically considering 'name' info of objects using this RuleBasedCollator? Do you have any idea or suggestion about that for me ?

Comment: Ok i got the solution to sort the array list as i wanted according to above comment .... :)

Comment: Great example: now I can sort strings the way it should. But what about objects? I have tried but get the error: <code>com.mycompany.myapp.model. MyClass cannot be cast to java.lang.String</code>. :-/

Answer (score 5):

Try this

For an Object

```
class MyObject
{
  public String name;
  public int score;
}
```

If you want to order by name (in this case using Norwegian language), you can do this

```
Locale locale = new Locale("nb", "NO");
final Collator collator = java.text.Collator.getInstance(locale);

Collections.sort(your_array, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2) {
        return collator.compare(obj1.name, obj2.name);            
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! I tried sorting objects with a CollationKey object but the result was totally wrong. This is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html). This is a type of [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that performs locale-sensitive String comparison.

Without knowing about the Norwegian language/characters, I think you'd want to use the following code:

```
Collator noCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("no", "NO"));
noCollator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Locale locale = new Locale("nb", "NO");
    final Collator collator = java.text.Collator.getInstance(locale);
    
    Collections.sort(your_array, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2) {
            return collator.compare(obj1.name, obj2.name);            
        }
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).